# How to replace backslashes to slashes for ${basedir} property in maven profile profile

Tags: groovy, maven, profile, pom.xml

I have a pom.xml with defined property **module.basedir** that is intended to contain transformed **basedir** property. It is defined as follows:

```
<properties>
    <module.basedir>${basedir}</module.basedir>
</properties>
```

And I have following code that is executed using mgroovy plugin:

```
<source>
    println project.properties['module.basedir']
    project.properties['module.basedir']=project.properties['module.basedir'].replace('\\','/');
    println project.properties['module.basedir']
</source>
```

Later I use this property in other plugins. This works fine until I move plugin definitions into maven profile. And when maven profile is activated mgroovy plugin works fine, but when I access property in the next plugin I get unmodified value.

This is how I access this property:

```
${module.basedir}
```

It looks like that when profile is executed it creates own copies of properties defined in project and they are used when referenced from plugins.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I faced with the same problem using gmaven-plugin on windows to create EJB module description. I'm not a savvy in Groovy, but this approach works for me:

```
def basedir = project.properties['module.basedir'].replace('\\','/')
def md = (basedir + "/target/module.xml" as File)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String path = '\\a\\b\\c'
assert path.replaceAll('\\\\', '/') == '/a/b/c'
```

So you need to replace this line:

```
project.properties['module.basedir']=project.properties['module.basedir'].replace('\\','/');
```

with

```
project.properties['module.basedir']=project.properties['module.basedir'].replace('\\\\','/');
```

The reason you need 4 backslashes, is because each of the double-backslashes in the source String (`path` in my example) must be escaped.

Comment: This is not the case, I can see string changed in the output. The point is that when I write **print ${module.basedir}** I still get original value.